# preg_match to determine similar pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
$lines ="Where to find train station";
$pattern = "/Where ([^\s]+) find train station/i";

preg_match($pattern, $lines, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Above code is works fine, but If put

```
$lines ="Where can I find train station";
```

this doesn't work. How to solve problem like this? Is it possible if work with this word also?

```
$lines ="Where can i and you and me find train station";
```

Can anyone please suggest how to detect similar pattern even one or more word is in between.

Thank you in advance

Comment: $pattern = "/%Where (?=.*find) %train station/i";

this also not working

Comment: I'm not clear on what exactly you're trying to accomplish here. Can you elaborate?

Comment: If $lines = "Where can I find train station" Or $lines = "Where to find train station" I want recognize as the same pattern.

Comment: Comparing to mysql syntax it would be something like "where * find train station"

Comment: Gotcha. How about `"/Where (.*?) find train station/i"`? [Try it](https://repl.it/repls/HeartyLastingRay). I'll post it as an answer if this is what you want.

Comment: It works great ! Thank you so much ^ ^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `(.*?)` to match and capture arbitrary characters between `where` and `find train station`.

`.` matches any character, while `*?` is a [lazy quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), consuming as few characters as necessary to match the pattern.

Here's a working example:

```
$pattern = "/Where (.*?) find train station/i";

$tests = [
    "Where to find train station",
    "Where can I find train station",
    "Where can i and you and me find train station"
];

foreach ($tests as $test) {
    preg_match($pattern, $test, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(27) "Where to find train station"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "to"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(30) "Where can I find train station"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "can I"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(45) "Where can i and you and me find train station"
  [1]=>
  string(20) "can i and you and me"
}
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/HeartyLastingRay)